# Error data.frame: undefined columns selected, Shiny R, lapply()

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, reactive

I am trying to replace NA values by column mean by lapply(). The below functions works absolutely fine in normal R,

```
 i1<- sapply(temp1, is.numeric)
    temp1[i1]<-lapply(temp[i1], function(x) replace(x,is.na(x), 
  mean(x[!is.na(x)])))
```

But the when I am trying the same inside reactive expression, it says undefined columns selected.

```
    num_na<-reactive({
    file1<-input$file
    temp1<-read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, 
           header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
  # create logical set for numeric columns
  i1<- sapply(temp1, is.numeric)
  temp1[i1]<-lapply(temp[i1], function(x) replace(x,is.na(x), 
  mean(x[!is.na(x)])))

 })
```

Please help me on this. Its really hard to work with reactive function. Please advise on this. I am creating another reactive expression as I will be calling the same in lot of other actionButtons() in shiny.

Comment: temp1 is any dataset.

Comment: you forgot an 1 `lapply(temp[i1]` should be `lapply(temp1[i1]`

Comment: Thanks bro. you are amazing.